# python using spearmanr on a not equal number of rows from a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Hey I want to use spearmanr correlation on data that I have.

```py
df = pd.read_csv('Dafniyot_Data.csv',delimiter=',')
#grouping data by C/I groups:
CII = df[df['group'].str.contains('CII')]
CCI = df[df['group'].str.contains('CCI')]
CCC = df[df['group'].str.contains('CCC')]
III = df[df['group'].str.contains('III')]
CIC = df[df['group'].str.contains('CIC')]
ICC = df[df['group'].str.contains('ICC')]
IIC = df[df['group'].str.contains('IIC')]
ICI = df[df['group'].str.contains('ICI')]

F1a = stats.spearmanr(CCC['N_offspring'],CIC['N_offspring'],nan_policy='omit')
F1b = stats.spearmanr(CCI['N_offspring'],CII['N_offspring'],nan_policy='omit')
```

As you can see I divided them by groups, but the problem is that not always I have the same number of observations in each group although I need so to use spearman.

I don't want to delete rows of observations in each group in the csv until I have the same number in all of them.

Instead I ask if there a way to do something like this:

if X rows is bigger then Y rows, select randomly from X rows until you have Y rows

thanks!

Comment: The two arrays you calculate a correlation between need to have _some_ actual relationship that links a point in array X to a point in array Y, else the correlation is meaningless. The fact that you have a different number of observations in your arrays indicates that this doesn't exist so whatever "correlation" you are trying to calculate is meaningless.

Comment: Thanks! my project is in biology and due to the nature of the experiment the sizes of the groups are not identical. it is common to omit information (under certain criteria). in this case we have 2 groups of 30 animals (started with 30 observation), but some were disqualified during the experiment and the sizing of the group changed. what would you suggest? should I omit all observations above the lowest amount of observation to match the smallest group?